# Are beforeEach blocks in the same scope run sequentially?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm pretty sure I read this somewhere, but I can't find the documentation now. If I have two `beforeEach` blocks in the same `describe` block, are the guaranteed to run sequentially? IE:

```
describe("foo", function(){
  beforeEach(function(){
    print("I'm always first!");
  }

  beforeEach(function(){
    print("I'm always second!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use one then?

Comment: @Pavlo Because my use case is a bit more complicated (Angular `module`/`inject`s and such).

Comment: yes,It is executed sequentially.Otherwise you can write beforeEach with injected module right after your test cases

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN If you put that in an answer and point me to a reference, I'll accept it :).

Comment: ok.Will come with example

Comment: @DavidGrinberg it's sequential, just look at the source code of jasmine.js ;)

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I have updated answer with referance.Let me know if it is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html

> Calls to describe can be nested, with specs defined at any level. This allows a suite to be composed as a tree of functions. **Before a spec is executed, Jasmine walks down the tree executing each beforeEach function in order**. After the spec is executed, Jasmine walks through the afterEach functions similarly.

Here is the sample code of my current app.

`nodeApp` is main module

```
describe("\n\nuser registration form testing", function() {

    beforeEach(module("views/createuser/createuser.html"), function() {

    });

    describe("\n\nUser createtion form should have valid data", function() {
        beforeEach(module("nodeApp"));  
        beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile, $controller, $templateCache) {

        }))

    });    
});
```

If  I put the `beforeEach(module("nodeApp"));` after the `second beforeEach`
its throwing an error.Because `nodeApp` is the module responsible for injecting the all services.
So,later it is available for injection in second `beforeEach`

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the source code of the Jasmine in Suite.js it adds them in the reverse order than in which they are added.

```
Suite.prototype.beforeEach = function(fn) {
    this.beforeFns.unshift(fn);
};
```

Then in the Env.js you can see that before they are run they are reversed:

```
var beforeAndAfterFns = function(suite) {
  return function() {
    var befores = [],
      afters = [];

    while(suite) {
      befores = befores.concat(suite.beforeFns);
      afters = afters.concat(suite.afterFns);

      suite = suite.parentSuite;
    }

    return {
      befores: befores.reverse(),
      afters: afters
    };
  };
};
```

As the whole time they are kept in Array, I would say that yes they are executed sequentially all the time.

Comment: Wait.. really? They place them in reverse order then... reverse them and end up with regular order? Whats up with that? Either way, as long as they are run in order its all fine I guess.

Comment: I am not really sure why the do it this way. In the code, they are unshifting beforeEach and afterEach, while beforeAll and afterAll are normally pushed into the array. 
Then before the processing, they actually reverse the order of beforeEach meaning they should run in the same order as declared while they retain this for afterEach so that afterEach run in different order than declared.